# how to prevent gradient vanishing in deep learning?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, gradient-descent

I train a CNN model using convolution layers from Resnet50(I freeze all layer in Resnet50). But the loss won't change during epochs running. I think this call gradient vanishing. I am new to Deep Learning so I want to hear from you guy how can we prevent this problem ?

[image: loss didn't change]
[image: CNN_structure]

I expect some counter method for this problem

Comment: please show code for creating your model and also code for providing data into your model.

Comment: I don't know how to upload file to stack overflow,here my drive you can view (filename Resnet50_model). https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1vl2n9U0u1er5uJJ5t34RerhnOdeKTcY_

Comment: All model is ok except Resnet50_model.

Answer (score 0):

You can try whether to change the algorithm of the gradient or change the weights initialization method.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).